# Proof of subadditivity of a probability measure

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

> We want to show that $P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} C_i\right) \leq
>  \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} P\left( C_i\right)$.
>
> Let $D_n = \bigcup_{i=1}^n C_i$, and $F_n = D_n -
>  D_{n-1}$ for all $n \geq 2$.
>
> \begin{align} P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n C_i\right) &= P\left(D_n\right)
>  \\  & = P\left(C_1\right) + P\left(\bigcup_{i=2}^nF_i\right)\\ & \leq
>  P\left(C_1\right) + \sum_{i=2}^{n} P\left( C_i\right) \\ & =
>  \sum_{i=1}^{n} P\left( C_i\right). \end{align} Hence we have that
>    $P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} C_i\right) \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} P\left(
>  C_i\right)$.

Am I correct in understanding that the third step holds because $F_n \subset C_n$ for all $n \geq 2$?
Also, am I correct in assuming that the final step extends, without loss of generality, to a countably infinite sequence of sets, as stated originally?

Comment: I think you mean $D_n=\bigcup_{i=1}^n C_i$. And yes, $F_n \subset C_n$ holds.

Comment: @Ian Whoops. You are absolutely correct.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Proof:

Based on the fact when n=2：

we have $P(\bigcup_{i=1}^2C_i)\le\sum_{i=1}^2P(C_i)$.

Assume $P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1} C_i\right) \leq
 \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} P\left( C_i\right)$ holds for all $n≥2$,

$P(\bigcup_{i=1}^nC_i) =P((\bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1}C_i)\bigcup_{}C_n)\le P(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1}C_i)+P(C_n) \\
 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \leq\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} P\left( C_i\right)+P(C_i)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} P\left( C_i\right) $

Therefore, the finite subadditivity of a probability measure has been proved.